# How objects are added to data structures - is just their reference added?

Tags: java

When adding an object to a data structure the reference to the object is always added, not the object itself. So below code snippets are fundamentally the same ?

```
Snippet 1 - 
    Object objectRef = new Object();   
    Vector vector = new Vector();
    vector.add(objectRef);
    Object object = (Object)vector.get(0);

Snippet 2 -
    Vector vector = new Vector();
    vector.add(new Object());
    Object object = (Object)vector.get(0);
```

Comment: Snippets are exactly the same in question as asked

Comment: yep, just noticed myself, ive updated

Comment: BTW: `Vector`is rarely used in current Java. You probably should prefer `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java always passes references by value.  So whenever you use a reference as an argument to a function call, the reference value is *copied*.  The object itself is not passed, a copy of its reference is.  Its an important distinction to understand.  It also is important to understand that with the reference you (or the library) can still operate on the object passed via its reference.

Your snippets are not entirely the same.  In (1) you end up with two references to the same object, `objectRef` and `object`.  In (2) you end up with only 1, `object`.  In both cases the vector has a *different* reference to the object.

Answer (score 0):

Both snippets are the same, the only difference is that you have a location variable named objectRef which can be modified after it was added to the vector, if it is modified, it will be reflected in the object returned from the vector as well since it IS the same object.  Though the "Object" class doesn't exactly have any methods which can modify the object.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct.  In the java programming language there is only heap.  Every object exists out there in magic heap land.  Every non-primitive value is just a pointer whose only operation is to dereference.  A List can be thought of as a list of pointers to strings, the actual data content of the strings is out on the heap, not inside the collection structure.

(This is the semantics of the language of course.  Modern runtimes are under no obligation to actually do it that way, the JIT uses method stacks, it just has to behave exactly the same as if it worked that way.)

Answer (score 0):

They result in the same state except that at the end of snippet 2, you don't have a symbol called objectRef.

Answer (score 0):

Both snippets give the same results. The difference lies that in the first snippet you have three references to the same object (`objectRef`, `object` and a reference in `vector`), and in the second snippet you only have two references to the same object (`object` and a reference in `vector`).